# contact form jquery php phonegap - success issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cordova

i try to create a contact form in jquery php 4 phonegap, my problem how can i have response success from php? or if i can try other solutions but havent ideas 4 for the moment ^^
thx a lot

p.s. the form works (if i delete response success form js)

index.js

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function() {
$('#send').click(function() {
            var url = 'send02.php';
            var error = 0;
            var $contactpage = $(this).closest('.ui-page');
            var $contactform = $(this).closest('.contact-form02');
            $('.required', $contactform).each(function(i) {
                if($(this).val() === '') {
                    error++;
                }
            });
            // each
            if(error > 0) {
                alert('Inserisci tutti i campi obbligatori segnati con asterisco*.');
            } else {
                var email = $contactform.find('input[name="email"]').val(); 
                var datetime = $contactform.find('input[name="datetime"]').val();   
                var mobilephone = $contactform.find('input[name="mobilephone"]').val(); 
                var selectnative4 = $contactform.find('select[name="selectnative4"]').val();
                var message = $contactform.find('textarea[name="message"]').val();


                //submit the form
                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : url,
                    data : {
                        email : email,
                        datetime : datetime,
                        mobilephone : mobilephone,
                        selectnative4 : selectnative4,
                        message : message
                    },
            success : function(data) {
                        if(data == 'success') {
                            // show thank you
                            $contactpage.find('.contact-thankyou').show();
                            $contactpage.find('.contact-form').hide();
                        } else {
                            alert('Impossibile inviare il messaggio. Per piacere riprova.');
                        }
                    }
                });
                //$.ajax

            }
            return false;
        });


});
```

and send.php

```
<?php
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

if (isset($_GET["email"])) {
$email = strip_tags($_GET['email']);
$datetime = strip_tags($_GET['datetime']);
$mobilephone = strip_tags($_GET['mobilephone']);
$selectnative4 = strip_tags($_GET['selectnative4']);
$message = strip_tags($_GET['message']);
$header = "From: ". $firstname . " <" . $email . ">rn"; 

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$httpref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$httpagent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");    

$recipient = 'mark@facebook.com';
$subject = 'Prenotazione Online';
$mailbody = "

Nominativo: $email

Telefono: $mobilephone 

data prenotazione: $datetime

Scelta dal Menù: $selectnative4

Messaggio: $message 
in data: $today
";
$result = 'success';

if (mail($recipient, $subject, $mailbody, $header)) {
    echo json_encode($result);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: what if you replaced `echo json_encode($result);` with `echo 'success';` ??

Comment: Doesn't work, index.js waitin a success response from send.php

Comment: add `console.log(data);` before the line `if(data == 'success') {` and check the results in the console please

Comment: this is a msg... TypeError: jQuery19105036105164021705_1395573327376 is not a function

Comment: you have another issue with ur js code!

Comment: is your code inside on `DOM` ready function  ??
if not; please include it in the function this way `$(function(){ your code });` then try again.

Comment: Is your PHP file on an external server or in your app?

Comment: php is an exterl file server, maybe i need to jsonp callback

Comment: is a cross-domain contact form